# Window Form application into web

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

i have a window form application, now i want to run it into browser on server so that user can run it on server. 
What is the best way to do that 
The language is vb.net

Comment: Building a Web application is totally different then 'running a winform app in your browser'. Have a look at ASP.NET for building web applications on the .NET platform.

Comment: can it be done by converting it into activex control(.ocx) in vb6?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You must rewrite your application using ASP.Net language or use Windows Terminal Server & RemoteApp (it let your user to use the application in remote).

Comment: can it be done by converting it into activex control(.ocx) in vb6 or any way so that i can use the exe using flash sandbox?